# sql select rows based on column having duplicate values but order them distinctly

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I have a Table with these two columns

```
name  |  position
_______________
bob   |   1
rob   |   1
sam   |   1
tom   |   2
shyam |   2
ram   |   2
shah  |   3
sara  |   3
shiv  |   3
rogue |   4
logan |   4
xavier|   4
```

I need to order by distinct `position` but the duplicates should not be removed, the final result must be like

```
    name  | position
    _______________
    bob   |   1
    tom   |   2
    shah  |   3
    rogue |   4
    rob   |   1
    shyam |   2
    sara  |   3
    logan |   4
    sam   |   1
    ram   |   2
    shiv  |   3
    xavier|   4
```

I tried both distinct `position` as well as group by `position`, but both remove the duplicates but i want them to be grouped as sets of rows such that the first copy occurs then the rows of second duplicate occur etc.Any suggestions or help on achieving it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate the rows within each value of `position`.  Then you can use this for ordering:

```
select t.name, t.position
from (select t.*, if(@prev = position, @rn := @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @prev := position
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @prev := -1)
      order by position
     ) t
order by rn
```